# Computer shutting down after playing a graphical game

Tags: cpu, gpu

For a while, whenever i play a graphically intensive game, The computer just shuts down unexpectedly, with no warning.

These are my specs:

- Intel Quad Core Q6600
- AMD Sapphire R9
- 500 watts power supply
- windows 7

I have installed the new AMD Sapphire R9 recently, and after that, the computer shuts down.

The GPU and CPU temps are relatively low before it shuts down, BUT after a few minutes of going full screen on ULTRA. It shuts down.

**Could anyone help about what the culprit is?**

(i have suspicions on the power supply, since i put in a new graphics card on a 6 year+ old machine.)

Comment: Graphics cards use a lot of juice, so it may well be the PSU is not man enough for the job.

Comment: Please provide us the PSU requirements for your graphics card.

Comment: It might help if you didn't run it in Ultra mode, the rest of your computer's specifications, are to blame for the poor performance and using a more liberal setting might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd looked at the system requirements (printed on the box, and on the manufacturer's website) you'd see this little line there:

- 750 Watt Power Supply is required.

So I'd upgrade that measly little 500W PSU into *at least* a 750W one as your first port of call.

Comment: **thanks for the information!** ill see if it will work!

Comment: Agreed, the original Core2Duo's were fairly power hungry, and a decent Q6600 system was getting close to marginal with 500w back then. With an R9 sucking even more juice, and no doubt a PSU the same age as the CPU (so 5 years worth of capacity wear), the PSU is the likely culprit

Comment: @Csharper so, did you test with new PSU?

Comment: @Haplo Yes, The culprit for the old PSU was a high fluctuation of volts. It wasn't consitent. THANKS! (Sorry for being late)

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same problem back a while ago. Computer was  shutting down when i was playing games. I suspected it is from the heat. So, i got myself a 3 fan cooler and problem was solved. I think yours the same since it is happening after the installation of graphic card.

Edit: Was using single fan 6850.

Comment: Sudden shutdowns like that are invariably from one of two causes; over-heat or under-power. I think in this case, under-power was more likely.